# How to add an header to appscript Post response

Tags: javascript, http, google-apps-script, header, sveltekit

I can't add http headers to the response to allow my frontend to make requests, it is being blocked by the CORS policy, and I can't access the response

[example code](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ylzBn.png)

I tried to create "headers" in the dict response, and add the Access-Control-Allow-Origin but it didn't work

Comment: About `add an header to appscript Post response`, I think that in the current stage, this cannot be achieved.

Comment: Use [code fences](https://stackoverflow.com/help/formatting) to format your code. [Test formatting](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/3122/formatting-sandbox) before posting questions.